# Azure - Naming convention for resources

Tags: azure, naming-conventions

What is the best way to name resources in Azure?

I have seen some people name their resources with prefixing the resource group.
Example: `grp-1-myfunctionapp`.
Others add resource type, region and environment like `functionapp-westus-prod-fn1`.

How should I go about it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/naming-and-tagging

Comment: There is never a best way, it depends on your needs. Scale and structure of the organization can also have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An effective naming convention assembles resource names by using important resource information as parts of a resource's name.A public IP resource for a production SharePoint workload is named like this: `pip-sharepoint-prod-westus-001`

Straight From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/naming-and-tagging). Scroll down a little bit and you will find a whole bunch of great prefix to orginize your names.

**Please notice** that changing resource names can be difficult. Establish a comprehensive naming convention before you begin any large cloud deployment.